# How to get the correct tile position in Phaser.js with a zoomed camera?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am using Phaser.js 3.55 to build a tile-based game. I have a tilemap, a layer, and a player sprite. I want to be able to click on a tile and have the player sprite move to that tile.

However, I'm having trouble getting the correct tile position when the camera is zoomed in or out. I've tried using layer.worldToTileX and layer.worldToTileY to calculate the tile position based on the pointer position, but it gives me different results depending on the zoom level.

Here's my code for the pointerdown event in the update-function:

```js
function update (time, delta) {
    controls.update(delta);
    zoomLevel = this.cameras.main.zoom;

    this.input.on("pointerdown", function (pointer) {

        var x = layer.worldToTileX(pointer.x / zoomLevel );
        var y = layer.worldToTileY(pointer.y / zoomLevel );
    
        if (map.getTileAt(x, y)) {
            var goalX = map.getTileAt(x, y).x * 32 + 16;
            var goalY = map.getTileAt(x, y).y * 32 + 16; 
            this.tweens.add({
                targets: player,
                x: goalX,
                y: goalY,
                duration: 1000,
                ease: 'Power4',
            });
        }
    }, this);
}
```

What is the correct way to get the tile position based on the pointer position and the zoom level in Phaser.js?

At first I wrote the `pointerdown-event` in the `create()` function, which didn't update the zoom-scale I got by `zoomLevel = this.cameras.main.zoom;`. I took it to the update-function where zoomLevel would be updated, then trying to divide the current zoomLevel with the pointer.x and pointer.y. I expected the pointer so give me the currently clicked tile. Outcome: It shifted, depending on the zoomLevel.

My other code besides the update()-function

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
var map;
var layer;
var player;

function preload () {
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('tilemap', '/img/phaser/map.json');
    this.load.image('base_tiles', '/img/phaser/outdoors.png');
    this.load.spritesheet('player', '/img/phaser/dude.jpg', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
}

function create () {

    map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'tilemap' });
    const tileset = map.addTilesetImage('outdoors', 'base_tiles');
    layer = map.createLayer(0, tileset, 0, 0);
    player = this.add.sprite(500, 100, 'player', 4);

    var cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    var controlConfig = {
        camera: this.cameras.main,
        left: cursors.left,
        right: cursors.right,
        up: cursors.up,
        down: cursors.down,
        zoomIn: this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.Q),
        zoomOut: this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.E),
        acceleration: 0.06,
        drag: 0.0005,
        maxSpeed: 1.0
    };

    controls = new Phaser.Cameras.Controls.SmoothedKeyControl(controlConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the position with the function `getWorldPoint` of the camera *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Cameras.Scene2D.Camera.html#getWorldPoint__anchor))*, to get the exact position. No calculation needed

**Here a demo showcasing this:**
*(use the Arrow UP/DOWN to zoom in or out, and click to select tile)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 5 * 16,
    height: 3 * 16,
    zoom: 4,
    pixelart: true,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function preload (){
    this.load.image('tiles', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/super-mario.png');
}

function create () {
    let infoText = this.add.text(2, 2, )
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setScale(.5)
        .setDepth(100)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        
    // Load a map from a 2D array of tile indices
    let level = [ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[ 0, 14, 13, 14, 0],[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

    let map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 16 });
    let tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    let layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);
    const cam = this.cameras.main;
    
    let tileSelector = this.add.rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16, 0xffffff, .5).setOrigin(0);
    
    this.input.keyboard.on('keyup-UP', function (event) { 
        cam.zoom+=.25;
    });
    
    this.input.keyboard.on('keyup-DOWN', function (event) { 
        if(cam.zoom > 1){
            cam.zoom-=.25;
        }
    });
    
    this.input.on('pointerdown', ({x, y}) => {
        let {x:worldX, y:worldY} = cam.getWorldPoint(x, y)
        let tile = layer.getTileAtWorldXY(worldX, worldY);
        
        tileSelector.setPosition(tile.pixelX, tile.pixelY);       
        infoText.setText(`selected TileID:${tile.index}`);
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```